# Why is this question protected?

Tags: support, questions

This question https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3430/who-are-these-figurines-shown-worshiping-valerie-jarret-and-what-are-their-cons?noredirect=1#comment15076_3430 was reopend, but for some reason, it has been protected.

It says that only users with more than 10 rep can answer, but I have no ability to answer.  I don't intend to, but others may have the same problem.

Comment: "To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation **on this site**" - The bold part means you must earn that 10 rep through your contributions on Politics. You haven't, all your rep on the site comes from the association bonus. That's why you can't answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protection is usually reserved for questions that have attracted very low quality answers from new users. When that happens, protection raises the bar by requiring at least 10 rep *earned on the site* to answer.

However, your question has attracted no answers so far. Thus, protecting it is a bit premature, and an unnecessary (right now) barrier. I've unprotected it.

If people think the question has *no* chance of attracting quality answers, then the proper action would be to vote to close it, not protect it.

Answer (score 1):

Itis a horrible question. Candidly, if I didn't implicitly trust @SamIAm, I would delete it. I think we are keeping it around for posterity.

Comment: Could you elaborate?